# iOS Custom Keyboard Icon

Tags: ios

I am developing a custom keyboard extension. Everything works so far, but ... Is it possible to give my custom keyboard an icon which iOS will show if it would be the next to show? I searched but i can't find anything.

Example: If i only have the text and emoji-keyboard the Globe/ABC-Button changes to an emoji if the next keyboard is the emoji-keyboard.

[image]